# MySQL Join Subcategory

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have the categories and pages tables. My table is structure is something like this :

pages one has three columns

```
id | category_id | content
1         2        example page of subexample
2         1        example page of example
```

categories one has four

```
id | is_parent | parent | name
1       1         NULL    example
2       0          1      subexample
```

I want to get the all pages of that category, if its parent, i want to include the pages which are the member of its sub categories also.

With the example i gave, think like, when user selected to see the whole contents of the example category, i want him to see the example page of example and example page of subexample.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `category_id` = :cid
union
select * from `pages` p
join `categories` k ON k.id = p.category_id
where k.parent = :cid";
```

i've tried the above code, but not worked for me. i'm not sure with my logic also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pages
 WHERE category_id IN
(
  SELECT c.id 
    FROM categories c LEFT JOIN categories p
      ON c.parent = p.id
   WHERE p.id = :cid OR c.id = :cid
)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pages p
 WHERE category_id IN
(
  SELECT :cid
   UNION ALL
  SELECT id 
    FROM categories 
   WHERE parent = :cid
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd3f/5)** demo

**Note:** it will only work for one level deep meaning category and its subcategories only. If a subcategory were to have other subcategories then you need to use dynamic SQL to traverse the categories tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pages.* FROM pages,categories
WHERE pages.category_id=categories.id 
  AND (categories.id=:cid OR parent=:cid)
```